# 802.11n Airport Express automatically choosing to extend 5Ghz network instead of 2.4 Ghz

Tags: wifi, airport

I have a latest model (2012, 2.4Ghz/5Ghz simultaneously) Airport Express serving WiFi for my house. I have an older model, 802.11n, Airport Express set to "extend a wireless network". On the new AE I have *both* the 2.4 and 5 GHz networks with the same SSID.

The difficulty is that the older AE, which can only do one band at a time, always chooses to extend the 5 GHz network instead of the 2.4 GHz network, which is what I want.

I've tried changing the SSIDs of the 2.4 Ghz and 5 Ghz networks to be different and having the old AE extend the 2.4 Ghz one. That works fine. If I change the SSID's back to match, however, the older AE will *switch* which network it extends from the 2.4 GHz one to the 5 GHz one.

I find this odd behavior and I can't find a workaround. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean the older AE is broadcasting on the 5Ghz band or that it just picks the existing network on the 5Ghz to extend?

Comment: I'm not sure I know the distinction, but I have two networks now operating at 5GHz - the old AE and new AE. I'd rather have two networks on the 2.4 GHz band. I can't figure out how to tell the old AE to extend the 2.4 GHz one, not the 5 GHz one.